# Polymer using core-selector - how to set selected value with array

Tags: javascript, html, polymer, web-component

I am using polymer 0.5 and specificly the core-selector element:

```
<core-selector multi valueattr="label" id="specialisms" layout horizontal wrap around-justified>
    <div class="item core-selected" label="label1" active>Boo</div>
            <div class="item core-selected" label="label1" active>Baa</div>
            <div class="item" label="label1">Cow</div>
</core-selector>
```

How can i give multiple selected values with an array? What is the best way of doing this?

Is it possible to give the keys in like this:

selected="['key1','key2','key3']"

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use a `multi-selection`

**HTML**

```
<core-selector selected="{{multiSelected}}" multi>
    <div>Item 0</div>
    <div>Item 1</div>
    <div>Item 2</div>
    <div>Item 3</div>
    <div>Item 4</div>
</core-selector>
```

**Javascript**

```
Polymer({
    ready: function() {
        this.multiSelected = [0,1,2];
    }
});
```

*or when you're not working in a custom element*

```
<script>
    document.addEventListener('polymer-ready', function(e) {
        var tmp = document.querySelector('#template');
        tmp.multiSelected = [0,1,2];
    });
</script>
```

The `selected` attribute takes an array of numerical indexes

Taken from the [core-selector demo](https://www.polymer-project.org/0.5/docs/elements/core-selector.html)

Comment: How is this possible in the main page? Do i have to make a custom element to execute the javascript? Do i need a template element? I tried using your code and get this error:
Uncaught Element name could not be inferred.

Comment: You should look at the source code (Ctrl+U) of the [core-selector demo](https://www.polymer-project.org/0.5/components/core-selector/demo.html) to find out how to add this to your main page

Comment: I made it work using a template element
`var tmpl = document.querySelector("#template");
    tmpl.multiSelected = [0,1,2]; `

Comment: Glad it worked for you. Updated my answer with a querySelector example

Comment: What you 've editted you must use a tempate is="auto-binding" element around your core-selector and get the template by javascript instead of the core-selector

Comment: That could be true, but this is *example code* provided to answer your question. The template-binding and whatnot is irrelevant to this question. To keep this answer understandable I should not expand it with useless information